# How to compare with date in mm/yy format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a column named 'exp_date' and date is as mm/yy. i.e: 07/17. I want to select all rows where exp_date is less than or equal to two months remaining from today. How can I do this?

Comment: What DBMS? Tag it, please. _edit: Ah, "my sql". That was easy to miss due to not being typeset correctly._ And what do you mean about format? Is the date stored in a `char` field? That seems bad. Or is it a proper `date`? If so, the latter doesn't have any inherent format.

Comment: most DBMS have something like Date_add where you can add value to a date.  Most also allow you to transform a string date into a date or datetime for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post which sql dialect you are using. I will assume sql92. The `CAST` function is the first step: `cast('20' || substring (exp_date,4,2) || '/' || substring (exp_date, 1,2) AS DATE)`. MSSQL uses '`+` instead of `||`. After that, compare it with `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'`. CAPS here are optional.